# Inside Django tests folder not able to import outer modules

Tags: django, django-tests

I am trying to create a tests folder in my django app.
My app has following structure:

```
myapp
myapp/tests/__init__
mtapp/tests/test_email
myapp/function
```

Now i am trying to import function inside test_email file.

and executing test case as

```
python manage.py test myapp
```

but this gives me error No module named function.

Please let me know the reason behind this.

First Edit: if i put "import ..function" then its working fine. but is it a right way to do it.

Note: I am using python version 2.7,
Django version 1.5.5

Answer (score 0):

It might be a case of some Cyclic import when you are using `from ...filename import function`.

It can be resolved by **importing the function locally** in the TestCase.

Comment: I believe this is not a case of cyclic import.